# ¿Cómo leer .txt en Lenguaje C?

Tags: c

Archivo .txt cuyo contenido es:

```
Héctor Rengifo 18221202
```

Y le hago el siguiente código en C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char ifilename[] = "entrada.txt";       /* Declara el archivo */
   char name[30];       /* Declara variable nombre */
   int ci;       /* Declara variable Nro. de identificación */

   FILE *ifp;       /* Declara apuntadores a archivo */

   ifp = fopen(ifilename,"r");       /* Abre archivo de entrada */
   fscanf(ifp,"%s %d",name,&ci);       /* Lee datos de entrada */
   printf("NOMBRE: %s   CI: %d\n",name, ci);       /* Escribe los datos en pantalla */
   fclose(ifp);       /* Cierra el archivo */
   return 0;
}
```

Me trae en pantalla:

```
   NOMBRE:Héctor CI:0
```

Pero quiero que traiga:

```
   NOMBRE: Héctor Rengifo   CI: 18221202
```

Falta que traiga el apellido "Rengifo" y el número de identificación "18221202"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema esta en el momento en el que encuentra el espacio que separa el nombre del apellido. Al encontrar esto deja de leer la información.

Prueba a crear una segunda variable `char` que guarde el apellido y esto debería resolver tu problema.

Otra opción es modificar el `fscanf(ifp,"%s %d",name,&ci);`

De esta manera leera tambie los espacios en blanco:

```
fscanf(ifp,""%[^\n]c", %d",name,&ci);
```

Comment: ¡Excelente! Gracias, opté por crear una segunda variable y me funcionó.

¡Muchas gracias! luego probaré con la otra sugerencia que hiciste.